# Spring @Transactional doesn't work with other annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

So my Spring education continues. Currently I'm trying to learn some of the annotations and the things they bring to Spring 3. So I've got a mini webapp that can connect to a DB and put stuff in through a form and display records and so on. Everything works fine. I decided to try and get Spring to auto-detect the service bean that I have marked as @Transactional but doing that stops the app from saving to the DB. So:

```
@Transactional
public class ReservationServiceImpl implements ReservationService {
```

that works. I have a bean declaration of this class in my springcourt-data.xml files. No problems. When I do this though:

```
@Transacational
@Service("reservationService")
public class ReservationServiceImpl implements ReservationService {
```

it no longer works. And I do have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt" />
```

in the springcourt-servlet.xml file. So can anyone tell me what I'm screwing up? All I do is add another annotation to this class and remove the bean definition from the xml file and it no longer saves data to the DB. I can still query records and stuff from the DB though so obviously it's using the autodetected service bean.

Here are the config files:

```
springcourt-servlet.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="com.springcourt.web.ReservationBindingInitializer" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

And:

```
springcourt-data.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="reservationService" class="com.springcourt.service.ReservationServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: couple of things why are you declaring reservationService in context and also annotating it @Service,also add the context component scan to the second context file that is listed after "And" in your posting.

Comment: You have a typo in "@Transacational". Correct it to "@Transactional"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use @Service and component scanning the bean is created by the context created by the  dispatcher servlet (mvc).  Since the transaction:annotation driven is defined in the root application context it doesn't apply to the beans in the servlets context.  You can verify this by removing the @Service and moving the bean definition to the servlet context file - you should see the same result.

Where as when you don't use component scanning - the bean is defined in the XML of the root application context.

The fix is to change the component-scan tag in the web layer to only include web layer classes - either by using a different base package or by using an include / exclude filter. Add another component scan in the root application context for the other beans.

Querying might be working because you might have a OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor / Filter configured.

Comment: Nope, no OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. At least not that I'm explicitly declaring. However, I attempted what you said and it seems to have worked. I declared a component-scan tag for the service package in the spring-court-data.xml file and left the other in the spring-court-servlet.xml file. Sort of like Prasanna Talakanti was saying above I guess. I clearly don't fully understand how the seperation of these files has an effect on different tags.

Comment: Just one more comment. I removed all my configuration from spring-court-*.xml files and placed it into an applicationContext.xml, going back to just using <context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt"/> and things work properly. So the problem was definitely something to do with how things were divided up between the two files. If anyone can point me to a clear explanation on how this hierarchy works I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Refer to section 13.2 of the spring mvc documentation - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html.  Putting everything in one file works - but is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can query DB via the same bean, your `@Transactional` works or you would often get an exception (at least with Hibernate). Most likely in save operation you get some runtime exception that causes transaction rollback. Try to find out what exception is and go from there.

---

Update

To see if `@Transactional` got applied, print stack trace from inside the method. If you see long stack trace with a lot of transactional interceptors that means transactional aspect works.

Comment: Of course I could be wrong but I don't believe that's accurate at all. I can remove the Transactional tag entirely and still query and retrieve data from the DB. My understanding is @Transactional only affects persisting data to the DB. Also, there are no errors. I can step through the code and put things in Try/Catch blocks and no exceptions are thrown that I can see.

Comment: You didn't mention what technology you use for persistence. Is it plain JDBC? In this case you may not need `@Transactional` as each statement can be run in it's own transaction (depending on configuration). That would equally apply to read and write. To see if `@Transactional` applied print stack trace from inside the method. If you see long stack trace with a lot of transactional interceptors that means transactional aspect works. I can hardly imagine data not being persisted without any error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not surprised I forgot something. I'm using JPA through Hibernate connecting to a MySQL DB. I added my config files above. Also, how can I print anything from the stacktrace if nothing is being thrown? I'll play around with it and see I guess.

Comment: To print stack trace just put Thread.dumpStack() in the method.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't realize that. Perhaps I'm using it in the wrong spot but I don't see any value in this. It just shows what methods the current thread is executing, one of which is the method that persists the object to the DB. There is no other info though, just method calls.

Comment: If you don't see a lot of Spring related method on stack trace (transaction interceptors, in particular) that means that class didn't get proxied and indeed `@Transactional` didn't apply. I'll look again in info that you provided and may be get better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and solve it.

1st you must separate your context:component-scan to web and data level, like this:

```
<!--in springcourt-servlet.xml -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt.web" />

<!--in springcourt-data.xml -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt.dao" />
```

2nd add to springcourt-data.xml

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

I hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Add context component scan to spring-court-data.xml

  ```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springcourt" />
  ```
- Test service in isolation, Create a JUNIT Test some thing like this

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:springcourt-data.xml"})
  @Transactional
  public class ReservationServiceImplTest()
  {
       @Autowired
       ReservationServiceImpl service;

       @Test
        public void validateContext()
        {
            Assert.assertNotNull(service); 
        }

        @Test
        @Rollback(false)
        public void save()
        {
           service.save(data);
        }

  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That specifically didn't seem to work, but combined with gkamal's answer it did seem to solve the problem. I clearly don't understand the hierarchy of the configuration files when they're broken up as I've done and no books I've read have really covered it at all.

Answer (score 0):

A very good alternative to what you have is to use the following: `

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
 public class AppConfig {
     (...)
 }
```

What you need to do is to inject everything in the same scope. One way is to change the ApplicationContext xml, as said before, another is to use the CGLIB like Spring proxies so that you get sub class based proxies and in there write your bean implementations and definitions.

Further reading:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html
- http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2005.html